# Переустановка OC

Tags: windows

Как часто рекомендуется переустанавливать операционную систему программисту (веб-разработчику)? И как часто вы переустанавливаете операциаонную систему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если грамотно пользоваться, то не нужно будет переустанавливать.
А вообще как настроение есть. 
Надо понимать, что разработчику порой не достаточно переустановить ОС, а еще нужно потратить кучу времени на установку другого окружения.
Лично я пользуюсь Acronis True Image и забыл, что такое пререустановка, в критичной ситуации тратиться 15 минут времени и все снова в порядке.

ЗЫ. Вопрос ваш, немного не по теме форума.